# Google Analytics stats integration

Tags: google-analytics, widget

I currently havea  google analytics account for all my sites and I was looking for a way to allow my clients to see their stats without me emailing them every month.

So wWhat I am looking for is a widget of sorts that I could include in my backend that would display tracking information without having to log into google analytics so that my clients can view their website stats while in that backend area. I use a custom backend so the easiest implementation would be the ideal.

Is there a possible solution to this? I looked on codecanyon, google analytics apps, etc and found nothing that really seemed to fit the bill.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S.

I don't need these stats to be displaying in real time necessarily and I know there are some legal limits based on Googles terms of service bit I just looking for a script that would get some basic usage information every so often so that I can have a display of it.

Answer (score 0):

If they are emailing you every month, put together a custom report for them and have GA send it out on a schedule. GA can mail any number or reports or custom reports in several different formats on a schedule of your choosing.

Much easier than building a custom widget for them and it doesn't require them or anyone else to log in or store credentials.

See [Can Google Analytics email my reports to me?](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57163) and [Email scheduler, PDF export, and a transition to the new Google Analytics interface](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/11/email-scheduler-pdf-export-and.html)